# How to enable edit cell for all cells of a column in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid which is editable. When the grid loads, i want all the cells of a particular column
to be in edit mode i.e. ready for data capture. I have tried this, but it only puts the last cell
in edit mode. How can i achieve this?

```
function doGridComplete()
{
    var ids = $("#myGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    var grid = $("#myGrid");

    var marksColIdx = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'marksObtained');

    var rowId = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
    {
    //Edit all cells
    grid.jqGrid('editCell', rowId, marksColIdx, true);
    rowId++;
    }
}

var getColumnIndexByName = function(gr,columnName) {
    var cm = gr.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
    for (var i=0,l=cm.length; i<l; i++) {
    if (cm[i].name===columnName) {
        return i; // return the index
    }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

I call the function `doGridComplete()` in `loadComplete` i.e.
`loadComplete : doGridComplete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend you to do this.

Which advantage will have grid if you set every cell in cell editing mode? The loading of the grid will be much slowly. If some cell is in editing mode that it display the data which *don't saved*. Only if editing will be stopped the cell will be saved. So it can be that the user will modify the data and the modified value **will not saved** at all. So some changed can disappear.

Moreover you will unable to use the methods like `getCell` and `getRowData` because the methods don't work with editing cells.

So if you implement what you asked you will have to do many additional work to make the changes of the user not discarded and you will have problem to access the data. I can repeat the first sentence of my answer: I don't recommend you to do this.

Comment: You are correct. I want the flexibility of the user entering all the values for all the cells at once so that i can manually submit all the values at once. Some of my users have poor internet connection, so editing about 100 row one after the other will take longer time (i.e. 100 trips to the server) than entering all the values once and submitting once. This is actually my reason for doing this. Please, what do you recommend.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu: The user unable to edit simultaneously many cells. The user edit one cell after another one. If you don't want that saving take place after modifying of every cell you can use *local editing* and then send all modified data to the server. If you need local editing you can first fill *local* grid: with `datatype: "local"` or `datatype: "json"` and `localonce: true`. Then you can use `cellsubmit: "clientArray"` (in case of cell editing). Additionally you can provide "Send to Server" button which get *all local data* with `getGridParam("data")` and send it to the server.